# NCO combine variables into 3rd dimension

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a netcdf file with the below variables

- Albers
- Band1
- Band2
- Band3
- x
- y
- time

Each band has dimensions (x,y).  I want to combine the bands into a single variable with dimensions (x,y,time).

Is that possible with NCO or another library?  Python or command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NCO's [ncap2](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2). If time is size 3, and each Band is interpreted as the band at a different time, then something like this will work:

```
ncap2 -s 'band=Band1*time;band[:,:,1]=Band2;band[:,:,2]=Band3' in.nc out.nc
```

If instead the Bands are independent of time then you must add a new dimension of size 3 to accomodate the bands, e.g.,

```
ncap2 -s 'defdim("band",3);Band[$x,$y,$band,$time]=0;Band[:,:,0,:]=Band1;....' in.nc out.nc
```

Good luck!